# Remote hot patch(upgrade) .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET 4.6.1 Console application running on a Windows machine which deployed in customer room, we need periodically upgrade (fix bugs, add features) it, but we can't every time reach the machine, even stop the application due to business requirement, so any solution for my situation to remote patch application without stop it?

I noticed the **ASP.NET** used the Technic of [`Assembly Shadow copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies), this is most likely I want, but is there better full solution?

Comment: download binary updates from a server somewhere. run your logic in hot-reloadable assemblies. you can achieve hot reloading using isolated app domains. Load your modules into an app domain, program is running, just unload them, swap them out for updates, and load them again.

Comment: yes this is the `Shadow copy`, I just want to confirm is there any existed full solution/library for doing this.

Comment: If you're looking for a library, then this question is off topic. From the FAQ: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."